# How to position chart.js legend on both sides of chart, instead of presets (i.e. top, bottom, left, right)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, legend, pie-chart

I am building a pie chart in chart.js and am looking to split the legend in half, showing each half on either side of the chart. I understand the options in chart.js only allow for preset positioning, like so...

```
legend: {
          position: "bottom" //or top or left or right
         }
```

... but where and what is the code to adjust how these labels are drawn, such that I may add my own rules to the library?

Comment: Best to ask the people who wrote the code.  The maintainers are listed on their github site: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js